# How to place json data in a jquery variable

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to load some text into a text field through jquery, using the keyup event. The text needs to be grabbed through json, and stored in the variable 'value'. How do I put the text stored in json into this variable? I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
   var value = html(json['total']);
```

I have extracted the relevant part of my jquery code below. Thanks.

```
var Run;
 $('input[name*=\'quantity\']').keyup(function(e){
 ctrl = $(this);
 $('.loading').remove();
 ctrl.before('<img class="loading" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" />');
 clearTimeout(Run);
 Run = setTimeout(function(){
  if (!ctrl.val() || ctrl.val() == 0) {
    $('.loading').remove();
    ctrl.val(qty);
    return false;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/quantity',
    type: 'post',
    data: ctrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
      row = ctrl.parent().parent();
      ctrl.parent().css('width',ctrl.parent().width());
      $('#content h1').html(json['cart_heading']);
      $('#cart_total').html(json['header_cart_total']);
      var value = html(json['total']);
      row.find('.total').html(json['total']);
      row.find('.price').html(json['price']);
      row.find('.total').prepend('<input type="text" value="' + value + '" name="total" />');

      html='';
      for (i in json['totals']) {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td colspan="5"></td>';
        html += '<td class="right"><b>' + json['totals'][i]['title'] + '</b></td>';
        html += '<td class="right">' + json['totals'][i]['text'] + '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
      }
      $('.cart-total table').fadeOut(500,function(){
        $('.cart-total table tr').remove();
        $('.cart-total table').append(html).fadeIn(500);
      });
      $('.loading').remove();
    }
  });
},800);
});
```

Comment: Do you have html function in your code? if no, there is an error in your code,  try    `var value = json['total'];`

Comment: Thanks undefined, your solution worked. Much appreciated!